Citroen C4 PIcasso completely dead until ignition turned on
So I've just got myself a 2008 C4 Picasso.  It runs fine but I've noticed that after locking the car with the remote, some time later the remote no longer works, I have to manually unlock it and the cars dead no interior lights or anything, then I turn on the ignition and everything comes back to life, car drives.  So I suspect this is something to do with economy mode not just putting the car to sleep but severing the electric connection all together, some thoughts are that the negative battery sensor is at fault (but would this completely power off the car?) I've done the BSi reset, the battery is strong. It starts the car well after all.  I cannot see on any citroen wiring diagrams to small two wire connector on the negative sensor, there's continuity from the pins into the cables but I don't know where these go. I have another picasso to compare against but where do i start?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Thanks for the advice I appreciate it, turns out the car had a shunt fuse in the showroom position

Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, accept the answer that you found most helpful. - From Review

@Chenmunka - This isn't a thank you. It's THE ANSWER posted by the OP.

@Andyg - You realize you can accept your own answer as the answer to your question?

i do now thankyou

I'd venture to assume there is a problem with the body control module (BCM). The BCM (in most cars) controls the delayed power off (ie: delayed radio off; delayed headlights off, etc) as well as responding to the fob signal to unlock the car. Since the BCM controls power to most everything which is on after you turn the key off, I'm betting once it cycles power off, power for it goes away as well. Basically, it's killing itself. Once you turn power back on through the key, it is re-energized and the cycle begins anew.
Other than replacement, I'm not sure how you could test it to see if it is the problem. Some BCMs have to be programmed to the vehicle its being installed on. I'm not sure if your Citroen is one of them. This is why I wouldn't suggest trying to see if it works by replacement, but it is an option.

Thanks for the advice I appreciate it, turns out the car had a shunt fuse in the showroom position
